# React.js scrollIntoView does not work after one click and moves the page up

Tags: reactjs, debugging, scroll, sidebar, js-scrollintoview

I am new to react and stack overflow
problem that I am facing is:-

- Two objects are define categories and Data.
- Using map function I generate a sidebar using categories. a div right next to it I generate another div with categories having a title from categories object, inside it I generate its data using Data object.
- defined a scrolling function using scrollIntoView. on click of the element on the sidebar it scrolls to the respected title div with whole page going up(I don't want the page to scroll up)
  (it works in firefox,edge,safari(except the whole page going up part)) but in Chrome/Opera
- it works only once and page goes up and then onClick does not work.
- if I scroll the page back then onClick works once and then stop working to make it work I have to scroll the whole page.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sidebar-problem-usgi0u?file=/src/App.js

**I don't know for what reason it works on the small window of CodeSandbox but does not work when you click Open in new window option(top right of the output window) for full screen view which represent the actual problem (in chrome)**

Problems:-

- Page goes up.
- Does not work in chrome/opera as intended.

what I want is not to make the page go up and what it is causing  for code to work in some browser and not in other especially chrome.

```
**App.js**

import "./index.css";

export default function App() {
  const categories = [
    { title: "A" },
    { title: "B" },
    { title: "C" },
    { title: "D" },
    { title: "E" },
    { title: "F" },
    { title: "G" },
    { title: "H" },
    { title: "I" },
    { title: "J" },
    { title: "K" },
    { title: "L" },
    { title: "M" },
  ];

  const Data = [
    { name: "aa" },
    { name: "bb" },
    { name: "cc" },
    { name: "dd" },
    { name: "ee" },
    { name: "ff" },
    { name: "gg" },
    { name: "hh" },
    { name: "ii" },
    { name: "jj" },
    { name: "kk" },
    { name: "ll" },
    { name: "mm" },
  ];

  const scrollToCategories = (item) => {
    document.getElementById(item).scrollIntoView({
      block: "start",
      inline: "nearest",
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="Header_body">
        <h2>Header</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="description">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
        <p>
          consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
          labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </p>
        <p>
          AUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
          nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="body">
        <aside className="body__sidebar">
          <nav>
            {categories.map((category) => (
              <p
                className={"sidebarContent"}
                key={category.title}
                onClick={() => scrollToCategories(category.title)}
              >
                {category.title}
              </p>
            ))}
          </nav>
        </aside>
        <section className="selections">
          {categories.map((category) => (
            <div className="content" id={category.title}>
              <p className="content_title">{category.title}</p>
              {Data.map((data) => (
                <p className="content_data">{data.name}</p>
              ))}
            </div>
          ))}
        </section>
      </div>
      <div className="footer"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

**style.css**

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 3vw;

  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #000;
}

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.Header_body {
  height: 6rem;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

.description {
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.description h2 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.description p {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
}

.body__sidebar {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 24vw;
  background: white;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebarContent {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 20px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebarContent:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.selections {
  overflow: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
}


.content_title {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.content_data {
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.footer {
  height: 4rem;
  background: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me in FireFox using your provided sandbox. Every time I click a letter on the left navigation panel, it scrolls that letter's panel into view.

I did notice a missing `key` in your 2nd iterator which could pose a problem:

```
{categories.map((category) => (
  <div className="content" id={category.title}>
    <p className="content_title">{category.title}</p>
    {Data.map((data) => (
      <p className="content_data">{data.name}</p>
    ))}
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have updated my question as I was encountering the issue in chrome.

Comment: In both Chrome and Firefox I see the same behavior. When you start, both the outer and inner window are scrolled to the top. When you click any letter on the left, it scrolls both the outer and inner windows down. At this point, the header is not-visible anymore, but the letter components are. Are you saying the problem is now that the outer window doesn't scroll to the top on subsequent clicks, and that only the inner window scroll is affected? Because that's normal.

Comment: my problem is that I don't want the page to go up and on clicking the sidebar nav right windows goes up and then it does not work until I scroll the whole page in chrome. In codeSanbox it works but when you click open new window and opens on the whole page in new tab which resembles the real world scenario it does not work after first click until you scroll the entire page. Chrome Version 110.0.5481.96